# Binary Search Recursively using Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to implement Binary Search Recursively using Javascript.

Assume the array is sorted.

Function Signature can look like this :

```
BinarySearchRecursively (ArrayGiven, x, p, r)
```

where ArrayGiven is an Array, x is the number we are looking for.
p is starting index and r is end index.

Any Jsbin/ Jsfiddle link would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it. With psedo code implemented in the comments on top.

This is js bin : https://jsbin.com/womenov/3/edit?js,console
Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Binary Search using Recursion
 * p.......q........r : range where p is start, r is end
 * Assume the array is sorted.
 * Procedure BinarySearchRecursively(ArrayGiven, x, p, r, q = 0)
 * if(p > r) return -1
 * q = Math.floor((p+r)/2)
 * if(x === ArrayGiven[q]) return q
 * else if(x > ArrayGiven[q]) set p = q+1
 *    return BinarySearchRecursively(ArrayGiven, x, q + 1, r)
 * else r = q-1 return BinarySearchRecursively(ArrayGiven, x, p, q-1)
 *
 */

function BinarySearchRecursively (ArrayGiven, x, p, r, q = 0) {
        if (p > r) {
            return -1;
        }
        q = Math.floor((p+r)/2);
    if (x === ArrayGiven[q]) {
        return q;
    }
    if (x > ArrayGiven[q]) {
        return BinarySearchRecursively(ArrayGiven, x,q+1, r);
    }
    return BinarySearchRecursively(ArrayGiven, x, p,q-1);
}

const TestArray = [2, 6, 8, 9, 11, 15];
console.log(`Given Element is at position : ${BinarySearchRecursively(TestArray, 2, 0,5)}`);
```

Comment: The comment is helpful, but you might consider using meaningful variable names to make referring to it less necessary

Comment: This looks like the text book algorithm. Since `p` will always start at  0 and `r` will always start at the end of the array, it seems like you should define those with default values so the caller doesn't have to pass them. The function can still pass them during the interior calls.  Also, it's not clear why `q` is a parameter of the function

Comment: I am passionate about javascript and trying to implement all the algorithm in javascript